133. Clone Graph: Node with value 2 doesn't exist in the original graph
I get a similar error with a different root cause compared to: Clone Graph LeetCode 133
Consider the below implementation. If I use a Node-type key for processed_node_map, the algorithm passes. If I use node.val as the key, I receive the error:
Node with value 2 doesn't exist in the original graph.
Question: Can anyone explain why this error is occurring? TYIA
Constraints and notes:

Node.val is constrained to be unique across nodes in the input.
This error is seen in a test case with no input value of 2.

class Node:
    def __init__(self, val = 0, neighbors = None):
        self.val = val
        self.neighbors = neighbors if neighbors is not None else []

from typing import Optional

processed_node_map = {}

class Solution:
    # solution: https://leetcode.com/problems/clone-graph/solutions/5092202/blind-75-beats-88-06-46-75/
    def cloneGraph(self, node: Optional['Node']) -> Optional['Node']:
        return self.dfs(node) if node else None

    def dfs(self, node):
        if node.val in processed_node_map:
            return processed_node_map[node.val]
        
        clone = Node(val=node.val)
        processed_node_map[node.val] = clone

        calculated_neighbors = []
        for child in node.neighbors:
            calculated_neighbors.append(self.dfs(child))

        clone.neighbors = calculated_neighbors
        
        return clone


Do not tag this question as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

I don't understand the question. Do you mean using processed_node_map[clone] = clone? That won't work because Node isn't hashable.

@Barmar it does work. check the URL and submit it to see

Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html

You could pass your processed_node_map (or visited nodes) to the dfs method.
class Solution:
    def cloneGraph(self, node):
        if not node:
            return None
        return self.dfs(node, {})

    def dfs(self, node, processed_node_map):
        if node in processed_node_map:
            return processed_node_map[node]

        cloned_node = Node(node.val)
        processed_node_map[node] = cloned_node

        for neighbor in node.neighbors:

            cloned_neighbor = self.dfs(neighbor, processed_node_map)
            cloned_node.neighbors.append(cloned_neighbor)

        return cloned_node

You're getting a WA (Wrong Answer) by getting:
Node with value 2 doesn't exist in the original graph.

which clearly states.
Note
Note that the Node() is already defined in their backend, and we don't know their details. You don't have to redefine it, you would just make a call to their Node(). This can be removed.
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val = 0, neighbors = None):
        self.val = val
        self.neighbors = neighbors if neighbors is not None else []

